# no match for ‘operator=’

Tags: c++, templates, move-semantics

In the following example, I am trying if I try to return by reference from `fun()` then it gives me warning as it should.

However when I try to return by value, I am expecting '`operator=()`' to get triggered,  but it is throwing the following error which I am not able to figure out why:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Auto_ptr2<Resource>’ and ‘Auto_ptr2<Resource>’)

note: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Auto_ptr2<Resource>’ to 
‘Auto_ptr2<Resource>&’
```

Surprisingly, `res2=res1` invoked 'operator=()' just fine!!!

```
template<class T>
class Auto_ptr2
{
        T* m_ptr;
public:
        Auto_ptr2(T* ptr=nullptr)
                :m_ptr(ptr)
        {std::cout<<"\nAuto_ptr CTOR called ";}
        ~Auto_ptr2()
        {
                std::cout<<"\n~Auto_ptr2 called\n";
                delete m_ptr;
        }
        // A copy constructor that implements move semantics
        Auto_ptr2(Auto_ptr2& 
        {
                std::cout<<"\nAuto_PTR2 copy constructor called";
                m_ptr = a.m_ptr; 
                a.m_ptr = nullptr; 
        }
        Auto_ptr2& operator=(Auto_ptr2& a) 
        {
                std::cout<<"\nAuto_ptr2 operator = called";
                if (&a == this)
                        return *this;
                delete m_ptr; 
                m_ptr = a.m_ptr; 
                a.m_ptr = nullptr; 
                return *this;
        }

        T& operator*() const { return *m_ptr; }
        T* operator->() const { return m_ptr; }
        bool isNull() const { return m_ptr == nullptr;  }
};
class Resource
{
public:
        Resource() { std::cout << "\nResource acquired"; }
        ~Resource() { std::cout << "\nResource destroyed"; }
};

Auto_ptr2<Resource> fun(Auto_ptr2<Resource> res3)
{
        std::cout << "\nres1 is " << (res3.isNull() ? "null" : "not null");
        return res3;
}

int main()
{
        Auto_ptr2<Resource> res1(new Resource);
        Auto_ptr2<Resource> res2; 

        res2 = res1; // res2 assumes ownership, res1 is set to null

        res2=fun(res2); //ERROR : error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Auto_ptr2<Resource>’ and ‘Auto_ptr2<Resource>’)


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so fun(res2) is an rvalue and would need either operator= to take a lvalref to const? OR other option is to overload operator= with argument as rvalue ref?

Comment: Your comment is correct.

Comment: Gentle suggestion:  Do not ever write a copy constructor or copy assignment operator with non-const lvalue-reference, for any reason, until you are an expert in C++.

Comment: Point noted. Would it be correct to say that fun(res2) is a lvalue which is implicitly converted to rvalue and hence res2=fun(res2); requires an operator = with rvalue ref?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're writing something similar to `std::unique_ptr`.

So, as for `std::unique_ptr`, the `operator=()` should works with move semantics, so receiving a r-vale reference, `Auto_ptr &&`, not an l-value reference

```
     Auto_ptr2& operator=(Auto_ptr2 && a) 
    {
            std::cout<<"\nAuto_ptr2 operator = called";
            if (&a == this)
                    return *this;
            delete m_ptr; 
            m_ptr = a.m_ptr; 
            a.m_ptr = nullptr; 
            return *this;
    }
```

And the use should pass through `std::move()`

```
res2=fun(std::move(res2));
```

Same problem with constructors: avoid copy constructor (maybe delete it) and write a move constructor.

```
    Auto_ptr2 (Auto_ptr2 const &) = delete;

    Auto_ptr2 (Auto_ptr2 && a) 
    {
            std::cout<<"\nAuto_PTR2 move constructor called";
            m_ptr = a.m_ptr; 
            a.m_ptr = nullptr; 
    }
```

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the concept. `fun()` returns by value. `fun(res2)` is considered to be an rvalue even though it is lvalue. Would it be correct to say that fun(res2) is a lvalue which is implicitly converted to rvalue and hence `res2=fun(res2);` requires an operator = with rvalue ref?

Comment: @anurag86 - not an expert at this point but... it seems to me that isn't correct to say that `fun(res2)` is a lvalue.

Comment: Oh i thought, fun(res2) is an lvalue of type rvalue ref, which is implicitly converted to rvalue

Comment: @anurag86 more precisely, the expression `fun(res2)` actually is a prvalue of type `Auto_ptr2<Resource>`. The body of the function don't matter.